# get/setDlgItemInt for up-down controls

Tags: winapi

Can I get/set the value of an up-down control using the `getDlgItemInt`/`setDlgItemInt` functions? They send `WM_GETTEXT`/`WM_SETTEXT`. Does the up-down process these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up-Down controls don't have values, their buddy controls do. If you want to know the value, ask the buddy control.